# Check if datetime is between two datetimes

Tags: excel, vba

Hi i am trying to create a macro with vba 
An example would be

```
DATETIMEA  is  "20/11/2018 11:00:00 AM"

DATETIMEB is "20/11/2018 08:00:00 AM"

DATETIME  is "21/11/2018 07:59:00 AM"
```

I would like to check if the `datetimeA` falls between `datetimeb` and `datetimec` the code below doesn't work.

The values are stored in `Date` variables.

```
If datetimeb >=  datetime And datetimea  <= datetimec
```

Comment: You should [edit] your question and update all the discrepancies between your date strings. The 3 up top are in caps and there is no `C` date. You are also missing a date letter on your shared code. If your code has typos such as these, you should add `Option Explicit` to the **very top** of your code sheet and then try to run. `VBA` will call out any typos you may have (or other undeclared variables)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### VBA Solution

It's unclear how you are assigning dates to the variables so I will assume you already have that part complete.

Here are two methods to check the statement: `DateB >= DateA >= DateC`

```
Sub DateCompare()

Dim DateA As Date 'Variable Date
Dim DateB As Date 'Older Date
Dim DateC As Date 'Newer Date

DateA = Some Date
DateB = Some Date
DateC = Some Date

'Method to give Boolean Response
MsgBox DateA >= DateB And DateA <= DateC

'Method to do other things
If DateA >= DateB And DateA <= DateC Then
    MsgBox "DateA falls in-between DateB & DateC"
Else
    MsgBox "DateA does not fall in-between DateB & DateC"
End If

End Sub
```

---

### Non-VBA Solution

This can be done right in Excel without the need for `VBA`...
 `A2` = Variable Date
 `B2` = Older Date
 `C2` = Newer Date

> =AND(A2>=B2, A2<=C2)

The equation as is will return `TRUE` or `FALSE`. The equation can be nested inside an `IF` statement if you would like to return a non-boolean response like so

> =IF(AND(A2>=B2, A2<=C2) = TRUE, "A is between C & B", "A is not between C & B")